# Three dimensional representations of Alternating group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, invariant-theory

The alternating group $A_5$ has $2$ irreducible representation of degree $3$. The characters for these representations have irrational values. I guess the ring of invariants of these representations should be known in literature but I am not able to find them. Again the matrix entries are also irrational  numbers, so I can't compute the generators for the invariant ring in any of the computer algebra systems. Any reference in this direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: The 3-d complex reps of $A_5$ are here: http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/atlas/v2.0/alt/A5/#reps

Comment: Can't you compute these with Magma (probably Sage/Singular too)? $ $ C:=CharacterTable(AlternatingGroup(5)); IR:=InvariantRing(MatrixGroup(GModule(C[2]))); PrimaryInvariants(IR); Algebra(IR); FreeResolution(IR); HilbertSeries(IR);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $G_0$ be the image of $A_5$ under one of the $3$-dimensional 
representations, and $G = \pm G_0$.  Then $G$ is the group of
symmetries of the icosahedron, which is a Euclidean reflection group
(type $H_3$, Shephard-Todd #23).  Thus $G$ has a polynomial invariant group,
and in this case the generator degrees are $2, 6, 10$.  For invariants
$\phi_2, \phi_6, \phi_{10}$ we can take the Euclidean norm $x \mapsto (x,x)$, 
the product of six linear forms $x \mapsto (v,x)$ where $\pm v$ ranges over
$6$ pairs of vertices of the icosahedron, and the product of ten
linear forms $x \mapsto (v^*,x)$ where $\pm v^*$ ranges over
$10$ pairs of vertices of the dual dodecahedron.  The invariant ring
of $G_0 \cong A_5$ can then be recovered as 
${\bf C}[\phi_2, \phi_6, \phi_{10}, \phi_{15}]$ 
where $\phi_{15}$ is the Jacobian determinant of $\phi_2, \phi_6, \phi_{10}$
(and the product of linear forms $(e,x)$ with $\pm e$ ranging over
pairs of edge centers of either the icosahedron or the dodecahedron);
these generators satisfy one relation of the form
$\phi_{15}^2 = P(\phi_2, \phi_6, \phi_{10})$.

Comment: Can you clarify the wording of your third line: "Thus $G_0$ has a polynomial invariant group ..."?   (Here $G$ has order $120=2 \cdot 6 \cdot 10$ and has a polynomial algebra of invariants with generators of those degrees.).

Comment: Sorry, typo: $G$ has a polynomial invariant group.  Fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The part which is not clear to me is that how do you recover the invariants of $G_0$ from G ? Could you please give me a reference ?

Comment: You're welcome.  It's a general fact about Euclidean reflection groups $G$ that the invariant ring, call it $R$, is polynomial, and the orientation-preserving 
subgroup $G_0$ has invariants $R[\Delta]$ where $\Delta$ is the Jacobian
of the generators of $R$, is the square root of an element of $R$,
and is the product of linear forms vanishing on the planes of reflection.
Reference $-$ not sure what to suggest; it must be in the relevant chapter
of Bourbaki *Groupes et Algèbres de Lie*, but that must be overkill.

Comment: $A_5$ also has a $5$ dimensional irreducible representation. Can the matrices be viewed as a subgroup of some finite reflection group so that the ring of invariants can be computed easily ?

Comment: Not that easily, sorry.  It's contained with index $2$ in $S_5$,
but that invariant ring isn't easy either.  You can get that
representation by restricting from the $5$-dimensional representation
of $S_6$ to the *transitive* $A_5 < S_6$, and that $S_6$ is a Euclidean
reflection group with invariant degrees $2,3,4,5,6$; but the further
generators you must add to get the full invariant ring for $A_5$
(or even the transitive $S_5 < S_6$) still make it rather complicated.

Comment: Of course you could adapt the Magma code of @post.as.a.guest :
**C:=CharacterTable(SymmetricGroup(5)); IR:=InvariantRing(MatrixGroup(GModule(C[5]))); PrimaryInvariants(IR); Algebra(IR); FreeResolution(IR); HilbertSeries(IR);**
but that only confirms that the ring is complicated.

Comment: @ Prof. Noam D. Elkies: I am still looking for a reference for the fact that the invariant ting of a orientation preserving subgroup in an Euclidean reflection group is $R[\Delta]$ where $\Delta$ is the Jacobian of the basic invariants. I didn't find in Bourbaki (Ch.4-6). The factorization of Jacobian as linear forms vanishing on the planes of reflections is due to Steinberg.

Comment: As often is the case, I'm not a great source for references...
at least when the argument is more memorable than the 
biblographic information.  Here the invariants for $G_0$
are the direct sum of the invariants for $G$ and the "anti-invariants",
which are functions $f$ that transform under $g\in G$ to $-f$ when $g\notin G_0$.
The Jacobian $\Delta$ is anti-invariant; once you know it's
the product of reflection hyperplanes, it soon follows that
every anti-invariant is a multiple of $\Delta$, so we're done.